# What is a "control jungler"?

Tags: league-of-legends

I was playing with a Shyvana jungler earlier today. Our mid complained about not getting any jungle ganks, to which the Shyvana player replied, "Shyvana's a control jungler, she doesn't gank." I've never heard this term before, so needless to say I was puzzled.

Throughout most of the games I've played, jungling usually involved a lot of lane ganking, but apparently control jungling involves something different. What is "control jungling" and what attributes are useful for "control jungling".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A control jungler is one that maintains map control. Control junglers such as Shyvana are those that can easily counter-jungle, leaving the enemy jungler underleveled and underfunded. This in turn significantly decreases the potency of an enemy jungle gank.

Control junglers thus require a high degree of mobility. The ability to quickly move between camps, to be able to run to clear a ward and then return to safety quickly, and to be able to easily get in position for a countergank is important to control junglers. Shyvana, for instance, has her Burnout ability, which allows her to quickly cover large distances.

Another important aspect of a control jungler is control over map visibility. Shyvana in particular is good at this because she is innately tanky, making Oracle's Elixir a slightly less risky purchase. She also clears wards extremely quickly thanks to her Twin Bite ability.

To sum up, a control jungler exerts pressure over the enemy jungler while maintaining a map visibility advantage. A good control jungler requires mobility, fast clears, optionally a degree of tankiness, and the ability to quickly clear wards.

Just off the top of my head, I guess some examples aside from Shyvana would be Lee Sin and Udyr.

Comment: (Probably not coincidentally, everyone that M5's Diamondprox plays).

Comment: Does this mean that control junglers generally don't gank?

Comment: No they gank, all junglers should gank, the current exp and gold from camps in the jungle will put the jungler behind no matter who they play (Well maybe not udyr if he eats both jungles at once) unless they get a gank or two.

Comment: +1, but I wouldn't consider lee sin or udyr a control jungler. Lee Sin should be aggressively ganking lanes and snowballing himself, otherwise mid game he tapers and is fairly worthless outside of peels. A better example would be Nunu and Mundo; fast clears, high mobility.